# Botium Connector for Amazon Alexa Skills API "Access Denied"

Tags: bots, chatbot, botium-box

I am trying to use "Botium Connector for Amazon Alexa Skills API" by following the guide https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-alexa-smapi, but I am having the following problem:
after installing the connector via Botium-CLI, I run the command "npx botium-connector-alexa-smapi-cli init".
In the first step "Create Amazon Security Profile "I follow all the steps then entering Client-ID and Client-Secret.
In the second step "Get Amazon Authorization Code" once I click on the link provided and allow access I get the following error:

"Error Access Denied"

[image: 1]

Does anyone know how to fix this? is this a Botium problem or did I get some steps wrong?
Thank you

Does anyone know how to fix this? is this a Botium problem or did I get some steps wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Error access denied certainly hints at an issue with parameter you are using to pass this request via [Botium Connector for SMAPI](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-alexa-smapi). I would definitely recommend going over the Botium Connector documentation to ensure you are using the proper client ID and secret in the wizard steps. If issue persists, then you could open an issue with Botium connector for smapi on [github](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-alexa-smapi/issues)

Referring to Alexa documentation for SMAPI  – The client is the developer, tool, or organization that needs permission to be able to perform a list of operations on the skill by using SMAPI. The client can be the [Alexa Skills Kit Command Line Interface (ASK CLI)](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/quick-start-alexa-skills-kit-command-line-interface.html) (which uses SMAPI under the hood), another skill-building tool, or a developer who uses SMAPI to access the skill. The client ID and client secret of the security profile identify the client. The client [configures the ID and secret in the Login with Amazon (LWA)](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/get-access-token-smapi.html#configure-lwa-security-profile) console by using their Amazon developer account.

More details about [Alexa Skill Management API](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/get-access-token-smapi.html)

Note that Alexa already provides access to SMAPI available for Node.js, Python, and Java, which is one way to get started with SMAPI. With the SMAPI SDK, you can use any of the Skill Management APIs to programmatically manage your skills -[SMAPI SDK](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/smapi-overview.html#smapi-sdk) or  via [Alexa Skills Kit Command Line Interface (ASK CLI)](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/ask-cli-intro.html#manage-skill)